# load data to the form by the ID to update in laravel 5.2

Tags: php, mysql, laravel-5

I'm trying to populate the data to edit form. Here's my model

```
public function  EditBatch($id,$request){

  $data= DB::table('in_batch')
        ->where('id', $id)
        ->update(array(
            'id'=>$request->input('id'),
            'file_name' => $request->input('file_name'),
            'batch_type' => $request->input('batch_type'),
            'activity_type' => $request->input('activity_type'),
            'schedule_time' => $request->input('schedule_time'),
            'predecessor' => $request->input('predecessor'),
            'priority' => $request->input('priority'),
            'batch_remark'=>$request->input('batch_remark'),
            'approved_by' => Auth::user()->id,
            'approved_on'=>date("Y-m-d H:i:s"),
        ));
    return $data;
}
```

here's my controller

```
public function edit($id){
   $obatch = new BatchType();
   $batch_type = $obatch->GetBatchTypeDropDown();
   $batch = new ManageBatch();
   $batch->GetBatchById($id);
   return view('batch.edit', array('batch'=>$batch,'batch_type'=>$batch_type));
}
```

here's my view

```
{!! Form::open (array('url' => array('batch/update',$batch->id), 'class' =>  'form-horizontal', 'method' => 'post','id'=>'editbatch')) !!}

    <div class="form-group">
            {!! Form::label('batch_id', 'batch_id',array('class'=>'col-md-4 control-label')) !!}


        <div class="col-md-6">
            {!! Form::text('batch_id',$batch->id,array('class'=>'form-control','id'=>'batch_id')) !!}
        </div>

    </div>
{!! Form::close() !!}
```

when i trying to load the data to the view as above error is displaying

> Undefined property: App\Models\Batch\ManageBatch::$id (View: C:\wamp\www\hutch-in-portal\resources\views\batch\edit.blade.php)

how to solve this ?

thankyou

Comment: van you explain your `edit($id)` method, Explain each line please

Comment: please add code explaining each function in edit method. Most probably you are not calling `get()` or `first()` method while retrieving data.

Comment: Actually there are a lot of bad practices in this code. There's no need to get each request parameter one by one or set the User ID manually. Let Laravel do the work for you, setup eloquent relations and use request->all() - why do you have a GetBatchById function? use ->find() | if this is a edit view then use form model binding to easily setup the default data

Comment: Thanks for the help i have solved it

Comment: Well then you should at least provide the answer...

Answer (score 0):

well i found a solution and the mistake was in the controller method

public function edit($id)

```
{
    $obatch = new BatchType();
    $batch_type = $obatch->GetBatchTypeDropDown();
    $ouser = new ManageBatchUser();
    $batch_user = $ouser->GetUserDropDown();
    $batch = new ManageBatch();
    $batch_details=$batch->GetBatchById($id);

    return view('batch.edit',array('batch_details'=>$batch_details[0],'batch_type'=>$batch_type,'batch_user'=>$batch_user));


}
```

since i'm passing a single row to the view . i must add the index [0] in return. finally it worked